# atan2 -2. 3. does not parse

Tags: ocaml

I got a parsing error when using atan2 on negative floats

```
# atan2 -2. 3. ;;

Line 1, characters 0-5:
Error: This expression has type float -> float -> float
but an expression was expected of type int
```

I have to use `atan2 (-2.) 3.` Why can the compiler not correctly parse `-2.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces are not significant outside of tokenization in OCaml. Moreover, `-` is always read as a separate token on its own. In other words,

```ml
atan2 -2.
```

is parsed as

```ml
atan2 - 2.
```

and is indeed a type error.

Comment: Loll Just wondering how this language survived:-)  Is it this bad in Haskell too?

Comment: We're definitely in opinion territory now, but in my estimation, Haskell syntax _can be_ cleaner, but the mental overhead is ***much*** higher. I would encourage you to adopt a more positive attitude towards the language as it will facilitate learning.

Comment: Resolve by using parentheses to disambiguate or by using ~: atan2 (-2.) or atan2 ~-2.